# Import a module from Node.js into a React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browser, tcp

I am new to javascript and react. I use [`create-react-app`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) from the [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) to create a local develop environment. Now I want to import [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) library like this:

```
//index.js
import Net from 'net';

//...Something else
```

But somehow the npm import the `net` from

```
var net = __webpack_require__(/*! net */ "./node_modules/node-libs-browser/mock/empty.js");
```

How could I get the right library imported?

Comment: try renaming the var net to something else

Comment: You can also use require in React. Can you try with require like how we import in node

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare I got the `var net = bababa...` from the chrome. it's something that npm compile from `import Net from 'net'`

Comment: @HemadriDasari I tried, but seems like the creat-react-app env automatically compile my .js file. I was using JSX format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't import a module from the Node.js core into a React app.

You need to find an equivalent of [`net`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) available on NPM and check if it works in a browser.

But I'm not sure you can open a TCP/IPC connection from a JavaScript app in the browser.

If you can use HTTP instead, you should look at [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: I found something like [`react-native-tcp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tcp), and it failed to compile. Maybe I didn't get the dependencies right. working on it..

Comment: You can't either call a React Native library from a React app. A React app is limited by what a browser allows you to do in JavaScript. A React Native app can use some native features available on mobiles that are not available in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can import node js modules from reactjs using "Browserify"

http://browserify.org/

> Browserify lets you require('modules') in the browser by bundling up all of your dependencies.
>
> Browsers don't have the require method defined, but Node.js does. With Browserify you can write code that uses require in the same way that you would use it in Node.